# Dollar sign inside closed parens

Tags: haskell, syntax, operator-keyword, dollar-sign

[Websocket snippet](https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/server.lhs#L108) has a statement that has dollar sign inside closed parens like this,

```
any ($ fst client)
```

Since haskellers use `$` sign instead of parens, why do we need parens here?

Why is there a `$` symbol between parens?

I tried to see if `$` is a function by doing

```
Prelude>:t $
```

But it threw the error, `parse error on input $`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Haskell, operators are just normal functions that have names made up of symbols and used infix by default. You can use them just like a normal identifier by wrapping them in parentheses:

```
λ> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

`$` is just an operator like this itself. It represents function application and is defined as follows:

```
f $ x = f x
```

You can get its type just like `(+)`:

```
λ> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Haskell operators can also be partially applied like normal functions, by wrapping them in parentheses with arguments to one side. For example, `(+ 1)` is the same as `\ x -> x + 1` and `(1 +)` is the same as `\x -> 1 + x`.

This applies to `$` too, so `($ fst client)` is the same as `\ f -> f $ fst client` or just `\ f -> f (fst client)`. The code snippet you have checks if *any* of a list of functions returns true given `fst client`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that these kinds of partial applications are called sections.

Answer (score 3):

`($ fst client)` is an operator section (just like `(+ 1)` or `(* 2)`) - it partially applies the operator to its right operand. A more verbose way to write it would be `(\f -> f $ fst client)`.

So you're applying `any` to a function that takes another function and applies that function to the argument `fst client`.